# What are possible explanations for the permeability of balloon rubber, PET plastic and other synthetic materials for carbon dioxide?

Tags: classical-mechanics

Balloons are definitely not gas-tight. Carbon dioxide just leak by the rubber away. A balloon is filled with carbon dioxide. Knot in it. And play. Shrinkage. After an hour or two the carbon dioxide balloon has dramatically shrunk in size. Apparently carbon dioxide creeps much faster  through the rubber balloon than "ordinary air".

But why  carbon dioxide leaks through balloon rubber, and oxygen and nitrogen barely? Is an oxygen molecule not a whole lot more compact than a carbon dioxide molecule?

Similarly, it is still a hassle to keep bubbles inside plastic bottles, says a friendly product developer of a large beverage manufacturer. PET bottles are light and firmly and cheap, but especially the small disposable bottles of thin plastic, lose their carbon dioxide very quickly. You can get expensive, extra thick 'multilayer' bottles, those thick bottles, but usually is the choice simply filling under higher pressure, combined with short expiration date. The cola in the bottle can be just after the expiry date still safe to drink, but by that time there is not enough carbon dioxide left in order to be tasty.

What are possible explanations for that permeability of the balloon rubber, PET plastic and other synthetic materials for carbon dioxide?
Is one possible explanation that the gas easier 'dissolves' into all kinds of substances - including rubber?
Has the gas leakage through a balloon only to do with the "creep" of the gas molecules through the cracks of the rubber molecules maze?
Or has the gas leakage also to do with the degree of attraction and repulsion between the rubber and the gas molecules?

Comment: I wonder if this question turns out to be more about chemistry than physics, given that the size of an oxygen molecule is smaller than a CO2 molecule. I was not aware that CO2 diffuses more rapidly - if it does, I would ascribe it to chemistry.